# How do I match multiple conventional routes in a single controller in ASP.NET Core 2?

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-2.0

If I have these routes in my Startup.cs:

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            { 
                routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default_search",
                        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{searchString}"
                        );
            });
```

and in my Controller I have:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string searchString)
        {...
```

and

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {...
```

How do I match those with conventional routing?  It finds the search method but because my parameter is not named `id`, it doesn't get the `searchString` value, and it isn't using the second route that has `searchString`.  If I change the name of my parameter in the controller to be named `id`, it work.  Is this when I should start to consider Attribute routing?

Answer (score 1):

Route matching happens in the same order you mapped. so try this:
first define first in the template the exact link you want before your special variable like `Home/Search/{searchString}` and force it to a specific controller and action inside `defaults`

Then use the general template after this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "default",
          template: "Home/About/{sa}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" });

      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "default_search",
          template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      });
}
```

Comment: Then I will have the reverse problem.  I need the id one too.

Comment: how can you distinguish between urls of details of id 127 which will be /127 and searchstring 127 which will be /127 too - if you want another mapping tell me - but if that is the case as no difference in required url you can't make any program distinguish them

Comment: The name of the variable.

Comment: you need to give the two urls you tried because in if you are mentioning the variable names it should work - if your controller is Home then /Home/Details?id=5 will execute details and pass id with value 5 and /Home/Search?searchstring=7 will execute Search action and pass 7 as searshstring

Comment: How do you do it where you don't have ?somevar=x?  I want controller/index/value